# How do I set the "default page" in Google analytics if my site uses "friendly" URLs?

Tags: django, google-analytics

I have a website tracked using Google Analytics. It is a Django-based website, so all the URLs are "friendly" URLs (e.g., `/my/friendly/url/`) and don't have associated files like `index.html`, etc. Should the "default page" option in Google Analytics be left blank or set to `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the Google Analytics [help page](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=32995&hl=en_US):

> Your Analytics Profile Settings page
>   contains a field in which to specify
>   your default page. This information
>   allows Google Analytics to combine
>   hits to www.yourdomain.com and
>   www.yourdomain.com/index.html, which
>   are in fact the same page. If Default
>   page isn't specified, these would be
>   reported as two separate pages.

This suggests that in your case, any users coming to your site would never hit an `index.html` page or similar so you should be fine leaving it blank. I doubt setting it to `/` would do anything as this does not actually "point" anywhere and since the Analytics documentation doesn't mention I'd stick to leaving it blank.